# multiple objects for a single index in an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, object, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Is it possible to store multiple objects for a single index in an NSArray?

Comment: perhaps have an index point to another NSArray with multiple entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure there are many ways to do this with the most common being to assign a dictionary to each array element

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you probably just want to have an `NSArray` of `NSMutableArray`s. You can then call something like this:

```
[[array objectAtIndex:2] addObject:obj];
```

or

```
[[array objectAtIndex:2] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Instead of addObject shouldn't you use setObject: forKey:? Should objectAtIndex be objectForKey?

Comment: `setObject:forKey:` is for dictionaries, cool_me5000's answer is using two arrays

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how dynamic you want the multiple objects to be.  How about creating a very simple class with properties of the multiple objects?
*I was thinking about a struct but I don't think `NSArray`s like pointer objects.*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface myCompound : NSObject
{
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSColor* colour;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSRegularExpression* expression;

@end

@implementation myCompound

@synthesize colour;
@synthesize expression;

@end
```

And use this as the element type for NSArray
`NSArray<myCompound*>* myArray;`